# How to do piecewise linear fitting to a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix below:

```
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
score <- array(c(35,  40,  45, 59, 62, 71, 78, 65, 78, 82, 89, 85, 78, 88, 96, 98,
           56,  45,  45, 59, 65, 73, 79, 69, 79, 88, 89, 88, 72, 85, 98, 92,
           59,  47,  49, 62, 62, 73, 72, 69, 75, 81, 89, 88, 74, 85, 98, 92,
           56,  45,  41, 66, 65, 71, 71, 67, 72, 82, 81, 89, 72, 84, 91, 96,
           51,  42,  42, 69, 68, 79, 78, 62, 79, 83, 87, 85, 71, 81, 97, 99),dim = c(16,5))
```

I want to set 2008 as the breakpoint to do the piecewise linear fitting. I also want to know the intercept, slope and p value. I may have over 100 column in the future, is it possible to do piecewise linear fitting to every column data in the matrix once? Thanks.

I have tried the following:

```
stage1 <- year - 2000
stage2 <- (year - 2008) * (year >= 2008)
fm <- lm(score ~ stage1 + stage2)
summary(fm)
```

It appeared this information:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = score ~ stage1 + stage2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
variable lengths differ (found for 'stage1')

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, `stage1` has the exact same length as `year`. And `lm` can fit multiple regression models so the answer to the main question is yes, you can do it all at once (if the data is like the posted `score` matrix). Run `length(year) == nrow(score)`, it should return `TRUE`. If not you have found the error.